# Best Way to Winterize a Chainsaw?

Tags: chainsaw

I've seen conflicting advice on how to winterize a chainsaw.  One group says to run it dry, until there's no fuel left.  The other group says to add StaBil to the fuel and run the engine to coat the insides.

The two main concerns seem to be preventing the carburetor flaps (or whatever they are) from drying out and to keep any remaining fuel from getting sticky and coating the inside of the engine.

So I'm not sure what to do!  What are your thoughts?

Comment: What does it say in the manufacturer's instructions manual?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It's about small engine care and maintenance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of *those questions* that elicits much gnashing of teeth, along with oil change interval and 87 octane vs. "premium". It comes down to opinion and the various factors:

- Length of storage (weeks, months, longer)
- Engine type (two-stroke vs. four, cylinder wall linings, carb type, etc.)
- Climate (humidity, temperature)
- Oil and fuel types

Running a two-stroke engine dry means depriving it of lubrication, if only for a few seconds. I'm not sure how effective residual lubrication is, and that probably depends on the oil type.

So, I personally like a hybrid program of sorts. I stabilize my fuel, and I run my machines every month or 6 weeks to normal operating temperature. This way they stay lubricated, the carburetor circuits don't dry out, and I don't run them without lubricant.